# Barcode code-128 Same value, different website

Tags: barcode

I was playing around with a barcode generator for one of my projects, and I realized that I get 2 different barcodes when I key in the same value on 2 different websites.

e.g. Keying in the value "0" on https://www.cognex.com/resources/interactive-tools/free-barcode-generator would result in a different spacing as compared to key in "0" on the website https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/?data=0.

I'm wondering why that is the case

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason might be due to one website using code128A, and the other website using code128B, resulting in a different barcode, yet having the same value. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.